# Enable input field after checkbox is checked in list of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of data getting from database, and i want to enable input field on checked checkbox. However its working only with the first line. Here is HTML code:

```
<?php
    require_once('inc/config.php');
    include 'verification/verify_form_details.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>getElementById example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        $result2 = getProcessID();
    ?>
    <label>Process: <small style="color:red;">*</small>             
    <?php 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
            $row[0] = cleanOutputData($row[0]);
    ?>      
    <div>       
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="process[]" id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>  value=<?php echo $row[0]?> /><?php echo $row[0] ?>
        </label>                                        

        <label>
        <input type="text" class="field" disabled name="number[]" id=<?php echo $row[0] ?> />
        </label>

    </div>
    <?php
        }
        mysql_free_result($result2);
    ?>
    </label>
</body>
</html>
```

And javascript function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.checkbox').change(function() {
                $('.field').attr('disabled',!this.checked)
            });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas how i can do it? Thank you

Comment: Because same `ID` use class instead. ID should be unique

Comment: @guradio I tried class and now after pressing on one checkbox its enabling all fields. edited my question also

Comment: use `$(this).parent().next().find('.field').attr('disabled',!this.checked)`

Comment: @guradio now all the fields are staying disabled even when checkbox is checked

Comment: please see answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
  $(this).parent().next().find('.field').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="process[]" id=v alue=/>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="text" class="field" disabled name="number[]" id=/>
</label>


<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="process[]" id=v alue=/>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="text" class="field" disabled name="number[]" id=/>
</label>


<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="process[]" id=v alue=/>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="text" class="field" disabled name="number[]" id=/>
</label>
```

1. Use class instead of ID
2. Use this context to refer to changed element